# common denominator

Tags: rationalising-denominator

What is the common denominator of the following:

$x^2-x$ and $2x$, $x^2$

(the first is the one side, and the other 2 are another side of the formula)

The full formula is:
$1/(x^2-x) = 1/2x + 1/x^2$

P.G

That's not homework. [I am a mother of 3](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/v/t1.0-9/11742747_10153530074177835_323378155905455515_n.jpg?oh=ef64a524caece6858764854cecf3d575&oe=56CD0C31&__gda__=1451635609_b3beeb10df4f4b76e5a512e9aeb2ad2f) trying to enjoy math again

Comment: I don't see a common denominator tag and I can't add a new one with my reputation

Comment: The common denominator of $\frac{1}{2x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is $2x^2$; that is what you need here.

Comment: To clarify:  are you asking which $x$ satisfy $\frac {1}{x^2-1}=\frac {1}{2x}+\frac {1}{x^2}$?

Comment: @vadim123 I need a common one with X^2-x

Comment: @lulu, well, I finally would need to reach what x satisfy - but first I need to find the common denominator - no?

Comment: No, you don't.  You can do it that way, but I think it is simpler to start by noting that every denominator is divisible by $x$ so multiplying both sides of the equation by $x$ makes life simpler.  Then combine the terms on the right and cross multiply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation is

$$\frac{1}{x^2-x} = \frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

To find a common denominator, the first thing to look for is if any of the current denominators can be factored. The first one can, as $x^2-x = x(x-1)$, so your equation becomes

$$\frac{1}{x(x-1)} = \frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

You then look for what each denominator is missing compared to the others. When I compare the first denominator $x(x-1)$ to the second $2x$, then the first one already has the $x$, but it is missing the factor of $2$, and when I compare the first denominator to the third $x^2$, I see that I am missing one factor of $x$ in the first to match the $x^2$ in the third. In total, I multiply the numerator and denominator of the first fraction by $2x$ to get

$$\frac{2x}{2x^2(x-1)} = \frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

The second denominator $2x$ needs to change to become equal to the new first denominator, because this is our guess of a common denominator - but to change $2x$ to $2x^2(x-1)$, I need only multiply by $x(x-1)$, because this is what is missing. Similarly, to change the third denominator $x^2$ to $2x^2(x-1)$, I multiply by $2(x-1)$. In total, you equation becomes

$$\frac{2x}{2x^2(x-1)} = \frac{x(x-1)}{2x^2(x-1)} + \frac{2(x-1)}{2x^2(x-1)},$$

and your common denominator is $2x^2(x-1)$.

Comment: Thanks! how do you format the forumulas so nicely?

Comment: No problem. I use something called "TeX commands" that this site supports. You basically use various commands for mathematics and incapsulate it in dollar signs. For instance, \frac{a}{b} is a fraction that gives you $\frac{a}{b}$ when you put dollar signs on each side of it. There's a quick guide here with further links: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation Also, you can right click on any of the math in my post and click  "Show Math As TeX Commands" to see the underlying commands.

Answer (score 2):

A common denominator is a polynomial that is divisible for all the denominators. Since $x^2-x=x(x-1)$, the simpler such polinomial is $2x^2(x-1)$ that contains all factors in the denominators.